# Kubernetes not pulling image with Docker for Desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using Docker for Desktop and Windows Server Core container.
I create a Docker image as follow:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

#Download NodeJs
WORKDIR /downloads
ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-x64.msi nodejs.msi

#Install NodeJs
RUN msiexec.exe /qn /i nodejs.msi
RUN setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

I use the commande `docker build -t winnode:1.0 .` to create the image, and everything goes well : I see with my VS Code docker extension that my image has been created.

Now I use a Kubernetes yaml file to run my image, as follow:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: winnode-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: winnode
    tier: webserver
  ports:
  - port: 3500
    name: http
    targetPort: http
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: winnode-dpl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: winnode
      tier: webserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: winnode
        tier: webserver
    spec:
       containers:
       - name: winnode
         image: winnode:1.0
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
```

However, kubernetes is trying to pull the image from the docker registry, and cannot find it. I get the message `ErrImagePull`. I googled it, and answers are talking about the `imagePullPolicy`. I have tried `IfNotPresent`, I get the same `ErrImagePull`. (this is the present example).

If I indicate `Never`, I get the error : `ErrImageNeverPull`.

What can I do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your kubernetes running? I imagine there is no way for it to reach your built container.

Comment: Kubernetes is embedded in Docker for Desktop, I enabled it.

Comment: How are you applying changes ? What kind of commands are you using ?

Comment: I use kubectl apply -f myfile.yaml

Comment: Actually I have the same problem with nginx image after pulling it. It seems the problem is not at all related to my own image, it's really something wrong at Kubernetes config level.

Comment: @Joel Were you able to resolve this issue ?  If yes, kindly post the answer as me too facing the same issue

Comment: @SathishKumar, unfortunately no, I test on Azure then, but locally I have never been able to test ever since.

Answer (score 0):

you need to push your winnode image to a repository. Kubernetes is designed to be operated from not a single machine. Set the repo name as your image tag and you'll be good to go

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use Docker for Desktop, and Kubernetes is the one embedded. It is supposed to work on a single machine, then I agree for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully at the  `kubectl`  command, it will find the "Client Version", but make sure it listClient Server.

Otherwise if you don't have Client Server enable the Docker Kubernetes cluster. For example install KinD and create your first cluster - [windows-wsl](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/#kind-kubernetes-made-easy-in-a-container).

You can also try to install Minikube.
Example how to install minikube and run on windows - [install-minikube-windows](http://john-cd.com/cheatsheets/Containers/Minikube_Install_on_Windows/#:%7E:text=Install%20minikube%20on%20Windows,-Minikube%20runs%20a&text=For%20Windows%2C%20install%20VirtualBox%20or,an%20uninstaller%20available%20as%20well.).

Take a look: [docker-desktop-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791214/how-do-i-deploy-windows-docker-containers-to-docker-for-desktop-kubernetes-clust), [dockerdesktop-vs-minikube](https://medium.com/containers-101/local-kubernetes-for-windows-minikube-vs-docker-desktop-25a1c6d3b766).